# Is there a way to assign a static IP when restarting the aws ecs service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Using Jenkins, I am configuring CI/CD.

We push the docker image to aws ECR, and then update the aws ECS service with the aws cli command.

The network interface and IP change when updating. Is there a way to fix this?

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster ${CLUSTER_NAME} --service ${SERVICE_NAME} --force-new-deployment
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the Network Interface and corresponding IP are on the individual Task(s) running in the ECS service, not the Service itself. There's no way to preserve the network interface/IP of the individual tasks within the service. Those IP addresses are subject to change any time new ECS Tasks are started, which may be due to an update to the service, or it may be due to auto-scaling events, or due to ECS replacing a failed task.

If you have something outside the VPC that needs to connect to the ECS service via a static IP then you need to place a [Network Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/network-load-balancer/) in front of the ECS service, and assign an Elastic IP to the load balancer. All incoming requests would then be sent to the Elastic IP.

If you have something outside the VPC that the ECS service is connecting to, and it is restricting those connections by IP address, then you need to place the ECS service in private subnets, with routes to a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html), and assign an Elastic IP to the NAT Gateway. All outbound requests would then appear to be coming from the Elastic IP assigned to the NAT Gateway.